# Connecting linker script with assembly file [risc-v]

Tags: assembly, linker, linker-errors, riscv

I'm using a [RISC-V compiler](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain), and I need to connect my linker script "variable" to assembly file instruction, for example:

In my linker script (.ld) I have this line:

```
ENTRY(_start)
_estack = 0x1FFFC;    /* end of RAM */
...
```

and from this, I need to create an assembly instruction in my start.S file, like this one:

```
li sp, _estack
```

I've tried many things, like:

```
.word _estack
# - or -
.global _estack

li sp, _estack
```

But none of them seems to work and it trows this message:

```
App/src/start.S: Assembler messages:
App/src/start.S:59: Error: illegal operands `li sp,_estack'
make: *** [build/start.o] Error 1
```

For context, here is my start.S file:

```
.global _start

.section .text.prologue, "ax"

.word _estack
# .global _estack


_start:
    li sp, _estack
    jal  ra, main
    j _exit

_exit:  j _exit
```

Comment: Why 0x1FFFC instead of  0x20000?  Are you reserving that last word of memory for something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one of those "just try it" things.

```
extern unsigned int _estack;
unsigned int fun ( void  )
{
    return(_estack);
}
```

assuming gcc examine the compiler output

```
fun:
    lui a5,%hi(_estack)
    lw  a0,%lo(_estack)(a5)
    ret
```

so, for gnu assembler (assembly language is specific to the tool not the target)

```
lui x15,%hi(_estack)
lw  sp,%lo(_estack)(x15)

_estack = 0x1FFFC;
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
}

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   000207b7            lui x15,0x20
   4:   ffc7a103            lw  x2,-4(x15) # 1fffc <_estack>
```

this should work too:

```
lui sp,%hi(_estack)
addi sp,sp,%lo(_estack)
```

and ori as well.

Just like any other constant you need to start with lui to get the upper bits set then you can deal with the lower bits in an other instruction.  The assembler might have a pseudo instruction for this where they choose the solution (for example if the constant was 0x12340000 you only need lui).  But assume that pseudo instructions are specific to the assembler not the target.

Comment: li is the pseudo instruction one would normally want to use here, but it doesnt seem to work with simply li sp,_estack so maybe more syntax is required.  I have issues with this whole put the stack in the linker thing but YMMV.  I would simply lui sp,0x20 in this case if it were me or lui sp,0x20000>>12 if the syntax supports it. (it is not a would, this is actually how I do it for risc-v).  YMMV

Comment: note it only took a few seconds of googling to find the answer.  I didnt need to spend the time on using the C compiler, even though that worked as well to find an answer.

Comment: Also note the stock gcc and binutils sources now include risc-v.

Answer (score 1):

In your crt0 file you need to replace: `li sp, _estack` by `la sp, _estack`. `li` is for immediate only , since `_estack` is a symbol you have to use `la`.

In your linker script you will need to provide the symbol, otherwise you will get an undefined reference error. replace
`_estack = 0x1FFFC;    /* end of RAM */`
by `PROVIDE(_estack = 0x1FFFC);    /* end of RAM */`.